# Java execute method in an existing thread

Tags: java

Suppose I have thread A and B running. How can I "call" a method from thread B such that the method is executed in thread A?

Comment: Use a producer-consumer type structure with a queue comes to mind.

Comment: I do not quite got your question.
You can call any methods from either thread. If you need add some collaboration between two threads, there are many approaches: queue, wait-notify

Comment: Could you provide more context on what you want to achieve as this is quite an open question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, thread A must implement some sort of request-queueing mechanism onto which thread B can enqueue a request.  Thread A must also provide a loop where it polls the request queue to dequeue and execute requests

This is standard producer-consumer architecture and is done, for example, when you use Swing Worker tasks that get run on their own threads, or when you all `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` which runs tasks on the EDT.